# Python: Combine Pandas rows based on content

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Relationship    Place   Full Name   Event Date  Birthdate

0   Vader van de bruid  's-Hertogenbosch    Lambertus Janssen   3-4-1847    NaN

1   Vader van de bruidegom  's-Hertogenbosch    Johannes Willem Gombert 3-4-1847    NaN

2   Moeder van de bruidegom 's-Hertogenbosch    Christoffelina Adriana Lotens   3-4-1847    NaN

3   Bruid   's-Hertogenbosch    Megchelina Janssen  3-4-1847    6-9-1817

4   Bruidegom   's-Hertogenbosch    Petrus Henricus Gombert 3-4-1847    19-5-1824

5   Moeder van de bruid 's-Hertogenbosch    Leena van Rooij 3-4-1847    NaN

6   Vader van de bruid  Dussen  Matthijs Schalken   3-5-1871    NaN

7   Vader van de bruidegom  Dussen  Leonardus Goossens  3-5-1871    NaN

8   Moeder van de bruidegom Dussen  Cornelia Nelis  3-5-1871    NaN

9   Bruid   Dussen  Huiberdina Schalken 3-5-1871    7-12-1851

10  Bruidegom   Dussen  Petrus Goossens 3-5-1871    2-2-1839

11  Moeder van de bruid Dussen  Adriana van Dijk    3-5-1871    NaN
```

I'm working with a dataframe containing marriage data.

[image: DataFrame]

The column "Relationship" can have 6 different values. What I'm trying to do, is combining rows into a new row. So for example, for every "Bruidegom" (Groom) I want the full name of his "Bruid" (Bride), etc. 
The problem is that I don't have all 6 "Relationships" for every groom and the order is also inconsistent.

Is there a way to combine this in a quick (2.8 million rows) way?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Remember you should copy/paste your sample as text, not image.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Quang Hoang My expected output is a new DataFrame with a column for each name. E.g. columnnames: Groom, Bride, Father of Groom,...

Comment: you want pivot, have a look at the infamous [pivot guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe).

Comment: I’ll definitely try that. Thanks!

Comment: What is the mapping id that maps. Bride and groom together. It looks like eventdate and place. But isn't that multiple couples marrigin each other on the same date.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen, eventdate and place are unfortunately the only mapping id's